# Forwarding active call

Tags: android

Is it possible, programatically, to initiate a call forwarding of the currently active call?

I'm not talking about doing this directly, I can't see this being a good idea, or even possible, but like when I initiate a call, where the user is sent to the built-in dialler app to make the call, I'd like to know if there is a similar function for transferring a call.

P.S.: There is another name for this, Call transfer.

Comment: what do you exactly want?? please describe a bit more

Comment: Do you mean to make the caller be able to talk with another guy by transfering the call?

Comment: It is rather simple really. The user have received a call, open my app, select another contact, and press "Forward to", the app will then send an intent to the dialler app to perform the forwarding. There are plenty of links about forwarding, but the common denominator is that is is for future incoming calls, and rely on vendor specific dial strings.

Comment: @Jermaine Xu, exactly. Some phones can do this from the build-in dialler app.

Comment: I just remembered that the function has another name, Call transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say that you can not do this from your app. I think The only way to do this is to create your own custom Build

Comment: That is what I'm afraid of.

Comment: Accepting answer, even if I didn't like it, it was the right one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do call forwarding after call is received on device
Why: Because call forwarding is done by network provider not by your device.

Process: 
- first you request call forwarding from network provider by using: MMI code 21. 
- Network provider will register your request and change call forward setting in your device.
 - When new call network provider will forward it directly and nothing will come to your device.
 [As shown in this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGkRU.png)