# Dynamic Android Call forwarding

Tags: java, android, telephony

I'm developing a mobile APP and I need to forward the incoming calls to different numbers based-on contact group. I divided my contacts into groups and each group has a different call forwarding number. When I receive the incoming call I should forward it based-on its group.

I wrote this code in PhoneStateListener in Call_State_Ringing:

```
package com.example.user2.callforwardnew;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class CallActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TelephonyManager telephonyManager =
               (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){
            if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){

                String url = "tel:" + "**21*" + "XXXXX" + Uri.encode("#");
                Intent intent1 = (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url)));
                intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
            if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone is Currently in A call",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){



                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"phone is neither ringing nor in a call",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
    telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

the problem is: When first call come it will not be forwarded it is only     register xxxx number in phone call forwarding. then second call will be forwarded in correct when.
the question :
How can I forward the incoming call based-on caller ID

Comment: _When first call come it will not be forwarded it is only register xxxx number in phone call forwarding_ Could you explain this better, this is unclear

Comment: first : phone call forwarding setting is disabled.
open : setting>My device>Call> additional setting>call forwarding > voice call.
 then the first call will come and phone will ranging and no call forwarded. But after first call come the phone call forwarding setting  will be enabled and xxxx number will be registered in phone call forwarding setting.

second income call will be forwarded to xxxx correctly.

Comment: Well, I guess the intent you have is to enable the settings (don't know this system). So I think this is logic. The call received that will enable the forward is already received, so it is to late to be forwarded. You could try manually. (not sure you could change the settings will receiving a call, but it probalby won't be forwarded if it is already ringing)

Comment: You are right " it is to late to be forwarded" ..  " not sure you could change the settings will receiving a call" ... How can I control the incoming call before ringing? ... I need my App to receive the incoming call not Phone...

Comment: The question is, why do you wait a call to set the forward, can't you set it based on the date, or using a button, ... . I don't think there is anything like a "pre-call entering". Once the call is receive, it is too late.

Comment: Because I want to forward my calls to more then one number based-on database.  
As I explained in my question: I need to forward call based on the contacts groups to different number not only one number. I will receive the call then check the caller group then forwarded to specific number.
I will divide my phone contacts to different groups then : 
If caller in family group then forward to xxxx
if caller in friend group then forward to yyy
if caller not in contacts forward to zzz  

This is why I'm not able to set the forward number by button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forwarding active call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101944/forwarding-active-call). This seems to be not possible

Comment: He need to transfer the active call ... I need to forward the incoming call to dynamic number before the phone ringing. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: But you need to forward the call based on the incoming numbers ... so the call is already active.

Comment: So the answer is " I think The only way to do this is to create your own custom Build" ..
How can I do it?
what is custom build ?

Comment: Just ask there, StinePike is still active (seen 17hours ago) so just ask more information on his answer. I can't help you more than pointing you where a similar question was asked

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This What I found. 
The answer is: We can't do call forwarding after call is received on our mobile 
Why: Because call forwarding is done by network provider not by your device.

Process:
 - first you request call forwarding from network provider by using: MMI code 21.
 - Network provider will register your request and change call forward setting in your device. 
 - When new call network provider will forward it directly and nothing will come to your device. 
 [as shown in this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fXF7.png)